# Docker Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this error after running this command in PowerShell
`docker-compose up`
My Docker Version
`Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350`
My Docker Info

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.0.0-beta.6)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.7
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc version: b9ee9c6314599f1b4a7f497e1f1f856fe433d3b7
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 12
 Total Memory: 12.43GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: 65YS:IH5I:4VI6:ZBXX:SB7J:NAR5:OSHP:OQ3S:ZGHX:653Z:KSFS:3CKX
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
```

Error

```
[+] Running 5/6
 - Network project_default          Created                                                                        0.7s
 - Volume "project_mongo-db"        Created                                                                        0.0s
 - Container project_mongo_1        Started                                                                       12.4s
 - Container project_node-app_1     Starting                                                                      12.9s
 - Container project_react-app_1    Created                                                                        8.9s
 - Container project_nginx-proxy_1  Created                                                                        0.1s
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/var/lib/docker/volumes/4b1671442c7499623e352a827a29d54b514fd4f186b937181a90ab497d12995c/_data" to rootfs at "/usr/src/server/node_modules" caused: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c11386ffc7cd58452b395472bb289e20df441f5b59e1082d6d055de466b81a4e/merged/usr/src/server/node_modules: read-only file system: unknown
```

This project I get from my friend. My friend didn't have Dockerfile in project folder but have just:
[image: Project Folder In Windows 10 File Explorer]

So I find so many tutorials and I find how to use docker-compose. It's like going well but I have this error. I find this error in google but no one can help me even in the StackOverflow. Thanks For Helping!!! :)

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    nginx-proxy:
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./nginx-proxy/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - '${NGINX_PROXY_PORT}:${NGINX_PROXY_PORT}'
        environment:
            - NGINX_LE_PLACEHOLDER_1=${PORT}
            - NGINX_LE_PLACEHOLDER_2=${SERVER_PORT}
            - NGINX_LE_PLACEHOLDER_3=${NGINX_PROXY_PORT}
            - NGINX_LE_TZ
        depends_on:
            - node-app
            - react-app

    react-app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile
        volumes: 
            - ./client:/usr/src/client:ro
            - /usr/src/client/node_modules
        depends_on: 
            - node-app
        environment: 
            - NODE_ENV=development
            - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
        ports:
            - '${PORT}:${PORT}'
  
    node-app:
        build: 
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./server/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./server:/usr/src/server:ro
            - /usr/src/server/node_modules
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=development
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        ports:
            - '${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}'
        depends_on:
            - mongo
  
    mongo:
        image: mongo:latest
        volumes:
            - mongo-db:/data/db
        ports: 
            - "27017:27017"
        environment: 
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=
volumes:
    mongo-db:
```

React Project Dockerfile (client):

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11

RUN apk add --update git
WORKDIR /usr/src/client
ENV PATH /usr/src/client/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY ./client/package.json ./
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps --silent

COPY ./client ./

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

nginx proxy folder Docker:

```
FROM 0x8861/nginx-le:v2.0.0
COPY ./nginx-proxy/templates/no-ssl.service.conf.dev /etc/nginx/no-ssl.service.conf
```

Node.js App Dockerfile (server):

```
FROM node:lts-buster
WORKDIR /usr/src/server
COPY ./server/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./.env ../.env
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

My Dockerfile Name:
[image: Dockerfile Image]

Thanks again to those who can help! :)
and if this is duplicate am so sorry but I can't find how to fix it thanks again :)
Another thing I tried doing it by a single project folder it can but have another error. and my friend suggest using docker-compose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to replace the application code in the image with different code using Docker bind mounts.  Docker's general model is that a container runs a self-contained *image*; you shouldn't need to separately install the application code on the host.

In particular, these two `volumes:` blocks cause the error you're seeing, and can safely be removed:

```yaml
services:
  react-app:
    build:             # <-- This block builds an image with the code
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile
    # volumes:         # <-- So delete this block
    #   - ./client:/usr/src/client:ro
    #   - /usr/src/client/node_modules
  node-app:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./server/Dockerfile
    # volumes:         # <-- And this one
    #   - ./server:/usr/src/server:ro
    #   - /usr/src/server/node_modules
```

Mechanically, the first `volumes:` line replaces the image's code with different code from the host, but with a read-only mount.  The second `volumes:` line then further tries to replace the `node_modules` directory with an old copy from an anonymous volume.  This will create the `node_modules` directory if it doesn't exist yet; but the parent directory is a read-only volume mount, resulting in the error you're seeing.

Comment: `services.node-app.build Additional property volumes is not allowed` New Error Helppp

Comment: Delete all of the `volumes:` blocks everywhere -- don't reindent or move them -- except for the `mongo-db` named volume.

Comment: `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 192.168.65.4:41428->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout` how to fix this error I don't know

Comment: `error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/aa/aad77ae58e0c58ad95794d3fe2df3ba770be6633cd4321bbf423d4555813c07d/data?verify=1628000808-gcDHb1iS9IvIkD6Wn6Eu78nONxE%3D: dial tcp: lookup production.cloudflare.docker.com on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 192.168.65.4:39028->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout` this error when comes to cmd with powershell